# Desenvolvimento de OS é restrito para iniciantes?

Tags: c, assembly

Uma coisa que sempre quis fazer é desenvolver o meu próprio sistema operacional (não necessariamente bom como Linux ou Windows, teria algumas funções básicas em prompt).

Não sou totalmente iniciante nessa área, já tenho uma "base" em Assembly e C.

Estou tendo dificuldade em encontrar guias sobre o mesmo (Me pareceu bastante restrito para iniciantes). Preciso de sugestões :P (Não posso comprar livros)

Comment: Literatura de boa qualidade você vai encontrar em artigos e livros (pago$). Recomendo Sistemas Operacionais do Andrew Tanenbaum. Recomendo também, que você estude bem os conceitos de SO e não tente implementar "da sua cabeça". Um SO funcional e sem bugs é algo extremamente complexo de se desenvolver do zero. Se você trabalha com microcontroladores, há muitas alternativas interessantes para serem estudadas. Você pode fazer modificaçoes no código, visto que a maioria é disponibilizado por uma licença GPL. Dê uma olhada no [BRTOS](https://code.google.com/p/brtos/) é uma maravilha =D

Comment: Eu diria que até certo ponto é sim restritivo, pois envolve uma gama muito grande de fatores que devem ser considerados, em contrapartida, qualquer leigo pode fazer um OS a partir de tutoriais e projetos que existem  internet a fora. Um guia que você pode usar é o [os.dev](http://wiki.osdev.org), inclusive há uma página sobre o assunto: [Conhecimentos necessários](http://wiki.osdev.org/Required_Knowledge) em *inglês*, dê uma olhada.

Comment: O C para fazer Sistemas Operativos é "freestanding". [Tens muitas limitacoes com freestnading C](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p6).

Comment: Alguns aventureiros brincam [disso](https://github.com/DaviAragao/aguilaOS) nas horas vagas.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Eu acredito que muitos já quiseram fazer isto, mas note uma coisa, você pode criar o seu próprio "OS", mas criar um núcleo é um caminho mais longo, em outras palavras para se criar um sistema você pode fazer o uso de núcleos conhecidos, mas para criar um núcleo será necessário fazer quase do "zero".

Se você usar um núcleo unix ou linux você pode criar um sistema operacional (note que linux e unix não são sistemas)

Criar um núcleo do zero pode ser algo complicado, veja por exemplo do MacOSX que  usa um núcleo baseado no núcleo do BSD (conforme a fonte o [XNU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU) é um núcleo hibrido que combina a versão 2.5 do [Mach kernel developed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_(kernel)) com componentes do [4.3BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution#4.3BSD)), o núcleo do BSD inicialmente era considerado um *branch* do Unix, então podemos presumir que ele é derivado do Unix.

Se você tiver interesse em criar um sistema você pode *adquirir* o núcleo linux acesse o https://gnu.org

### O que é um núcleo

Em computação, o núcleo (em inglês: kernel) é o componente central do sistema operativo da maioria dos computadores; ele serve de ponte entre aplicativos e o processamento real de dados feito a nível de hardware. As responsabilidades do núcleo incluem gerenciar os recursos do sistema (a comunicação entre componentes de hardware e software). Geralmente como um componente básico do sistema operativo, um núcleo pode oferecer a camada de abstração de nível mais baixo para os recursos (especialmente processadores e dispositivos de entrada/saída) que softwares aplicativos devem controlar para realizar sua função. Ele tipicamente torna estas facilidades disponíveis para os processos de aplicativos através de mecanismos de comunicação entre processos e chamadas de sistema.

Tarefas de sistemas operativos são feitas de maneiras diferentes por núcleos diferentes, dependendo do seu desenho e abordagem. Enquanto núcleos monolíticos tentarão alcançar seus objetivos executando todos códigos de sistema no mesmo espaço de endereçamento para aumentar a performance do sistema, micronúcleos executam a maioria dos serviços do sistema no espaço de usuário como servidores, buscando melhorar a manutenção e a modularidade do sistema operativo. Uma gama de possibilidades existem entre estes extremos.

<sub>fonte: [http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Núcleo_(software)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAcleo_(software))</sub>

> Note: Um sistema não precisa ter uma interface gráfica completa, como no windows, isto geralmente é uma aplicação em um nivel mais alto.

### Criando um Núcleo/Kernel

Como dito o núcleo é algo complicado, mas já que você tem algum conhecimento então irei lhe indicar http://wiki.osdev.org/Creating_a_64-bit_kernel

### Escrevendo um núcleo em C

A seguir mostra como criar um kernel simples em C. Este kernel usa o `buffer` modo de texto VGA (localizado na `0xb8000`) como o dispositivo de saída. Ele configura um driver simples que lembra o local do próximo caractere neste `buffer` e fornece uma primitiva para a adição de um novo caractere. Notavelmente, não há suporte para quebras de linha (`\n`) (e escrever o caractere vai mostrar algumas características específicas do VGA) e não há suporte para rolagem quando a tela é preenchida. Este exemplo é apenas o primeiro passo. Por favor, dedique alguns minutos para entender o código.

```
#if !defined(__cplusplus)
#include <stdbool.h> /* C não tem booleans por padrão. */
#endif
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* Verifique se o compilador acha que, se nós estamos alvejando o sistema operacional errado. */
#if defined(__linux__)
#error "Você não está usando um cross-compiler"
#endif

/* This tutorial will only work for the 32-bit ix86 targets. */
#if !defined(__i386__)
#error "Este tutorial precisa ser compilado com um compilador ix86-elf"
#endif

/* Hardware text mode color constants. */
enum vga_color
{
    COLOR_BLACK = 0,
    COLOR_BLUE = 1,
    COLOR_GREEN = 2,
    COLOR_CYAN = 3,
    COLOR_RED = 4,
    COLOR_MAGENTA = 5,
    COLOR_BROWN = 6,
    COLOR_LIGHT_GREY = 7,
    COLOR_DARK_GREY = 8,
    COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE = 9,
    COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN = 10,
    COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN = 11,
    COLOR_LIGHT_RED = 12,
    COLOR_LIGHT_MAGENTA = 13,
    COLOR_LIGHT_BROWN = 14,
    COLOR_WHITE = 15,
};

uint8_t make_color(enum vga_color fg, enum vga_color bg)
{
    return fg | bg << 4;
}

uint16_t make_vgaentry(char c, uint8_t color)
{
    uint16_t c16 = c;
    uint16_t color16 = color;
    return c16 | color16 << 8;
}

size_t strlen(const char* str)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    while ( str[ret] != 0 )
        ret++;
    return ret;
}

static const size_t VGA_WIDTH = 80;
static const size_t VGA_HEIGHT = 25;

size_t terminal_row;
size_t terminal_column;
uint8_t terminal_color;
uint16_t* terminal_buffer;

void terminal_initialize()
{
    terminal_row = 0;
    terminal_column = 0;
    terminal_color = make_color(COLOR_LIGHT_GREY, COLOR_BLACK);
    terminal_buffer = (uint16_t*) 0xB8000;
    for ( size_t y = 0; y < VGA_HEIGHT; y++ )
    {
        for ( size_t x = 0; x < VGA_WIDTH; x++ )
        {
            const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
            terminal_buffer[index] = make_vgaentry(' ', terminal_color);
        }
    }
}

void terminal_setcolor(uint8_t color)
{
    terminal_color = color;
}

void terminal_putentryat(char c, uint8_t color, size_t x, size_t y)
{
    const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
    terminal_buffer[index] = make_vgaentry(c, color);
}

void terminal_putchar(char c)
{
    terminal_putentryat(c, terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    if ( ++terminal_column == VGA_WIDTH )
    {
        terminal_column = 0;
        if ( ++terminal_row == VGA_HEIGHT )
        {
            terminal_row = 0;
        }
    }
}

void terminal_writestring(const char* data)
{
    size_t datalen = strlen(data);
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < datalen; i++ )
        terminal_putchar(data[i]);
}

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" /* Use C linkage for kernel_main. */
#endif
void kernel_main()
{
    terminal_initialize();
    /* Como não há suporte para novas linhas em terminal_putchar ainda, \n irá produzir algum personagem específico VGA vez. Isto é normal. */
    terminal_writestring("Hello, kernel World!\n");
}
```

Compile usando:

```
i686-elf-gcc -c kernel.c -o kernel.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra
```

Observe que o código acima usa algumas extensões e, portanto, nós construímos como a versão GNU de `C99`.

Depois veja o artigo: http://wiki.osdev.org/Creating_a_64-bit_kernel

### Criando sistema com GNU

> Em resposta: Para desenvolver um OS usando o linux ou unix precisa Assembly? Como posso aprender unix? –  misakie

Não é necessário Assembly para desenvolver em GNU ou GNU/Linux, como ambos são semelhantes irei fornecer um exemplo em `C` do GNU:

- Tutorial (assim que possivel irei traduzir e adicionar a resposta): https://cs.au.dk/~sortie/dopsys/osdev/
- Download do SRC e do iso prontos: https://cs.au.dk/~sortie/dopsys/myos/

### Criando meu sistema baseado em uma distro existente

Hoje muitos desenvolvedores linux utilizam como base distros já existentes, o Ubuntu começou sendo uma fork do Debian, hoje é praticamente outra distro, o LinuxMint é uma fork do Ubuntu. Estas distros já possuem bastante suporte para drivers, programas prontos (como `apt` por exemplo, que é o sistema de atualização/instalação/remoção de programas e da distro).

Você também pode usar uma distro pronta e criar o seu próprio sistema de interface gráfica, como o Cinnamon, Gnone, Lxde e KDE.

Para isto você pode usar o http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/ ou se você quiser apenas criar um Linux customizado, você pode seguir o passo á passo em http://www.tecmundo.com.br/tutorial/26134-como-criar-uma-distribuicao-linux.htm

Será necessário estar em um sistema baseado em Ubuntu (no Window não se é possível fazer isto):

### Requerimentos

- Ubuntu Builder;
- Imagem ISO da distribuição na qual seu sistema será baseado;
- Pacotes DEB dos aplicativos que deseja tornar padrão do SO.

A instalação do Ubuntu Builder pode ser feita por meio do Terminal do Ubuntu. Basta digitar os seguintes comandos:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:f-muriana/ubuntu-builder
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-builder
```

Depois de instalar o *Ubuntu Builder*, é hora de executá-lo e dar início ao processo de criação da sua distribuição. O primeiro passo para construir seu sistema operacional é selecionar a imagem ISO da distro no qual ele será baseado. Para isso, clique sobre a opção **Select ISO** e navegue pelos diretórios do sistema até aquele em que o arquivo está.

Caso você não tenha a ISO ainda, pode clicar em **Get Ubuntu** e marcar a versão do Ubuntu que deseja baixar. Na hora de finalizar o processo e gerar o arquivo da sua criação, o Ubuntu Builder faz o download do Ubuntu automaticamente. Mas lembre-se de que isso fará com que o processo final demore um pouco mais do que o de costume.

Antes de prosseguir com a seleção dos aplicativos e demais características, preencha os campos exibidos na tela principal com o nome da distribuição, nome-padrão de usuário para o liveCD e, por fim, o apelido com o qual a máquina será identificada quando o sistema estiver sendo executado diretamente do CD.

Depois isso, o trabalho mais pesado começa. Na parte mais à direita da tela, você encontra oito opções de configuração, cada uma delas responsável pela personalização de um item diferente na distro. A seguir, confira o que alguns desses botões permitem realizar.

A primeira opção permite que você selecione o ambiente gráfico a ser utilizado como padrão na distribuição que está sendo criada. Além dos já conhecidos GNOME e KDE, também é possível selecionar itens como **XFCE4**, **LXDE**, **OpenBox** e **BlackBox**.

### Editor sources.list

Clicando no segundo botão da coluna mais à esquerda, você pode editar a lista de repositório de aplicativos utilizada pela distribuição para baixar e instalar a maioria das aplicações. É preciso ter cuidado nessa etapa para não remover itens comprometam a integridade do sistema.

### Install deb packages

Se você quer que o seu SO tenha uma aplicação instalada, mas ela não pode ser encontrada no repositório padrão do Ubuntu, pode utilizar a opção **Install deb packages** para adicionar os pacotes de instalação de qualquer programa. Os arquivos DEB devem estar presentes no disco rígido do seu computador para que possam ser utilizados.

### Synaptic

O item **Synaptic** permite que você utilize o Synaptic para adicionar e remover pacotes ou aplicações. Sem dúvida, uma ótima opção para quem não tem muita paciência para editar algumas das configurações citadas acima utilizando o editor de texto.

Depois que você configurar todas as características da sua distribuição, é possível testar as opções clicando no botão **Test**, presente no canto superior direito da interface do Ubuntu Builder. Quando tudo estiver como o esperado, clique em **Build** e aguarde até o processo ser finalizado e a imagem ISO do SO, criada.

No botão **Settings** do Ubuntu Builder, é possível escolher qual ação o aplicativo deve tomar ao final do procedimento. Você pode, por exemplo, fazer com que a ISO criada seja imediatamente gravada em uma mídia.

O programa possui um assistente para a criação do sistema operacional, o qual pode ser ativado com um simples clique sobre a opção **Wizard**. O processo de configuração é bem parecido, e você pode personalizar as mesmas características. A diferença é que o Ubuntu Builder é quem decide quais itens serão modificados antes.

### Considerações finais

Para não ter problemas de espaço em disco durante a criação da sua distribuição, certifique-se de que há, pelo menos, 3 GB livre no HD do computador. Além disso, ter os pacotes DEB e a imagem do Ubuntu (ou do Mint) também ajuda a tornar o processo mais eficiente.

É preciso ter um pouco de paciência enquanto a ISO é construída. Dependendo da quantidade de modificações realizada e de aplicativo inseridos, a tarefa pode ser bem demorada.

<sub>Fonte: http://www.tecmundo.com.br/tutorial/26134-como-criar-uma-distribuicao-linux.htm</sub>

Comment: Para desenvolver um OS usando o linux ou unix precisa Assembly? Como posso aprender unix?

Comment: @misakie Como não temos "unix puros", então não sei qual unix lhe indicar, irei editar a resposta em breve e fornecer um exemplo com `gnu/linux`

Comment: `Nice job +1` =)

Comment: Dúvida resolvida. Obrigado Guilherme!